# Is it possible to use a variable in a layer filter?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to use a variable in a layer filter? For example, I'd like to have

```
"STATE" = @current_state
```

to only display the features within a certain state. Trying to do this gives me an SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables are used in QGIS expressions and can not be used for the *feature filter* functionality of the layer.

Please also see the answer to [QGIS query syntax differs between attribute table and feature filter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212393/qgis-query-syntax-differs-between-attribute-table-and-feature-filter/212398#212398) for detailed information about the difference.

What you could do instead for visualisation purpose is to setup a [rule based renderer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification) or use data defined symbology to make use of QGIS expressions with full variable support.

Comment: Could you use such variables in the **Advanced Filter (Expression)** option in the _Attribute Table_?

Comment: I didn't check but I don't see a reason why not.