# QGIS 3.4 feature filter maximum() does not work

Tags: qgis, filter, function

I would like to filter a layer with the maximum value of field_a, grouped by field_b. I tried this expression: `"field_a"= maximum ( "field_a","field_b")` But it doesn't work (there are no more features in the layer). When I use this expression for *Select by Expression*, the features are selected. Is there a way to filter them (without selecting)?

[Edit] I want to filter a existing layer (right mouse click -> filter). I don't want to select features or to create a new layer.

Comment: See this answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212393/qgis-query-syntax-differs-between-attribute-table-and-feature-filter/212398#212398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter query (`layer properties/source/provider feature filter`) allows you to specify an SQL `where` clause. If you enter `id=1` it will translate it to `select * from mylayer where id=1`.

From there, you can add a sub-query in this `where` clause to identify the IDs (or else) of interest:

```sql
field_a IN (SELECT MAX(field_a) FROM myLayer GROUP BY field_b)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I looked for!

Comment: @JGH sorry to ask but i don't see how to input SQL syntax in that part of the interface ... how do u do that ? where exactly are you ?

Comment: @snaileater layer properties, source, query builder

Comment: ok i was at the bottom **of the attribute table** ... but ... following your advice i don't succeed to enter full sql syntax (i mean using the FROM clause) ... there must be something i don't get ...

Comment: @snaileater I tested it with a Postgres layer and a Shapefile. It failed with an in-memory layer though, so this solution seems to be data provider-dependent

Answer (score 0):

If this is for visualization purpose, I suggest `Rule-based symbology`.

```
"field_a"  =  maximum("field_a", group_by:= "field_b" )
```

[image]

---

**[EDIT]**  To actually reduce the features by the expression, try **Extract by expression** tool (in  `Processing toolbox > Vector selection`).

The expression is the same as the above.

Comment: No, it is not for visualization purpose. I want to reduces the number of features in the attribute table with a filter. And unfortunatly the expression does not work with the filter.

Comment: @Nane Got that, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @ Kazuhita. Thank you for your help. Somehow I describe my problem not clear, sorry. I don't want to get a new layer, I just want to filter an existing layer (right mouse click on the layer, -> filter). But there this expression doesn't work...

Comment: @Nane Aah, sorry I misunderstood the question. I now understand this expression does not work,